# How do I set the scroll speed of a texture in world units?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make an infinite runner with objects coming from the side of the screen. However, the speed of the objects does not match the speed of the floor texture.

```
public GameObject floorPrefab;
public GameObject g;
float floorSpeed = 3.0;


void FixedUpdate () {
    //Floor
    floorSpeed += 0.001f;

    floorPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(floorSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0.0f);

    //GameObject
    g.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * floorSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Object and material should be traveling at the same speed in the `x` direction.

My floor is a `Quad` with a `MeshRenderer` that tiles 17 times in the `x` direction.

Comment: Good luck with that. Modifying the material's texture offset and converting that to world coordinates involves knowing a lot of variables and doing quite a bit of math. It would be easier to create background objects and moving them around.

Comment: The code depends on what `Renderer` you're working with. What kind of `Renderer` is the floor?

Comment: Mesh Renderer. Its a QUAD. I'm using a quad to move the texture as tiles so it looks like the floor is moving when really the texture is.

Comment: How much of the texture is shown on the quad? Does it show the whole texture exactly only once and it just wraps around, or does it repeat or only show part of the texture at a time?

Comment: The texture is tiled on the X axis by 17 and then scrolls on the X by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainTextureOffset` is in uv units and `Translate` uses world space units. You need a way to convert between them.

First, you need to know how many uv units long your renderer renders. This would be equivalent to what fraction of the texture it shows at once, or how many times it repeats on the renderer.

```
uVcount = 17f; // repeats 17 times in the scrolling direction
```

Then, you need to know how long the renderer is (in the scrolling direction) in world units. Because your renderer is axis-aligned, this becomes easy because we can just use `renderer.bounds.size` to find the volume of the mesh, and then `renderer.bounds.size.x` to find the length.

```
Renderer rend = floorPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>();
float rendererLength = rend.bounds.size.x;
```

So now all that's left is to convert `floorSpeed` from world units per `fixedUpdate` to UV units per `fixedUpdate`, and then use that as how much your offset changes:

```
float floorSpeedUV = floorSpeed  * uVcount / rendererLength;
rend.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(floorSpeedUV * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0.0f);
```

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
public GameObject floorPrefab;
public GameObject g;
public float uVcount = 7f; // repeats 7 times in the scrolling direction
float floorSpeed = 3.0;
private Renderer rend;
private float rendererLength;

void Start () {
    rend = floorPrefab.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rendererLength = rend.bounds.size.x;
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    //Floor
    floorSpeed += 0.001f;

    float floorSpeedUV = floorSpeed  * uVcount / rendererLength;
    rend.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(floorSpeedUV * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0.0f);

    //GameObject
    g.transform.Translate(-Vector2.right * floorSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Works perfect!! Thanks.

Comment: @briankirmu Don't forget to mark this answer as the chosen answer by clicking on the grey checkmark and/or upvote it so that other people with a similar question can find this answer and also give me some reputation points :)

Comment: And @briankirmu, this is exactly what I meant by "involves knowing a lot of variables and doing quite a bit of math." ;) Its not impossible, its just really difficult to work with.